# how to perform addition of numeric and string data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, concatenation

I have two types of data:

```
numeric (10)
string ('1 test')
```

I performed addition for both the inputs.

```
SELECT 10+'1 test';
```

result:

```
11
```

- It is giving result as 11?
- If any one knows please tell me?
- I tried a lot but I didn't get any answer?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: use `SELECT CONCAT(10,'1 test');`?

Comment: is you want to append the string to the number or something else you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(10, '1 test');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the output as `101 test`, 
you can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(10,'1 test');
```